# Fatal error 'early EOF' during git checkout in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, network-programming, eof

We have automated deployment jobs in Jenkins, which most often fail during the git checkout steps with the following error:

```
fatal: early EOF
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: index-pack failed
```

The git checkout commands itself in Jenkins is:

```
checkout resolveScm (source: [$class: 'GitSCMSource', 
    credentialsId: credentialsId, 
    remote: url, 
    traits: [[$class: 'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait'], 
        [$class: 'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.TagDiscoveryTrait'], 
        [$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckoutTrait'], 
        [$class: 'LocalBranchTrait']]], 
    targets: [branch, backupBranch])
```

We were initially using the https urls during the git checkouts, which were failing with the same 'early EOF' error, but in the details it mentioned curl. Due to this, we made the switch to SSH, which reduced the number of occurrences, but it hasn't gotten rid of them completely.

To try to debug this, I also defined the following environment variables:

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
GIT_TRACE=1
GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
```

This yielded the following additional information:

```
using credential <REDACTED>
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
Cloning repository ssh://git@<REDACTED>
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe init D:\Jenkins\workspace\<REDACTED> # timeout=10

Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@<REDACTED>
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10

using GIT_SSH to set credentials BitBucket DevOps SSH
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --no-tags --progress -- ssh://git@<REDACTED> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10

ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --no-tags --progress -- ssh://git@<REDACTED> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:

stdout: 

stderr: 23:48:34.354577 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '--no-tags' '--progress' '--' 'ssh://git@<REDACTED>' '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'

23:48:34.355576 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'D:\Jenkins\workspace\deploy@4\gitversion\<REDACTED>@tmp\jenkins-gitclient-ssh2369034223544784185.bat' '-p' '7999' 'git@<REDACTED>' 'git-upload-pack '\''/<REDACTED>'\'''

23:48:34.733576 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch< e38b8b86ad2fa170bba8de7c2460b3e00c357e5e HEAD\0multi_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow deepen-since deepen-not deepen-relative no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed allow-tip-sha1-in-want allow-reachable-sha1-in-want symref=HEAD:refs/heads/develop agent=git/2.16.2.windows.1

23:48:34.736576 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch< 1646cff9919cb3a96bd428bfeba21467a6444d92 refs/heads/develop

<REDACTED>: the same line as above for all branches that exist on the remote

23:48:34.742576 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch< 23761f5e94c8c51431276ae416a9bbef0fc72f5c refs/pull-requests/116/from

<REDACTED>: the same line as above for all pull-request that exist on the remote

23:48:34.742576 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch< 82a1d5a97371a973e1892de2978c8be686d701c2 refs/tags/<REDACTED>

<REDACTED>: the same line as above for all tags that exist on the remote

23:48:34.748577 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch< 0000

23:48:34.755576 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet'

23:48:34.792576 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch> want 1646cff9919cb3a96bd428bfeba21467a6444d92 multi_ack_detailed side-band-64k thin-pack ofs-delta agent=git/2.8.2.windows.1

23:48:34.792576 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch> want a5647247c1fb4ce54a292a8a7e020e6c028ffe52

<REDACTED>: the same line as above but with different commit ids

23:48:34.792576 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch> 0000

23:48:34.792576 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch> done

23:48:34.902576 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch< NAK

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Counting objects: 86496, done.

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:   0% (1/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:   1% (236/23551)   \15Compressing objects:   2% (472/23551)   \15Compressing objects:   3% (707/23551)   \15Compr

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2essing objects:   4% (943/23551)   \15Compressing objects:   5% (1178/23551)   \15Compressing objects:   6% (1414/23551)   \15Compress

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2ing objects:   7% (1649/23551)   \15Compressing objects:   8% (1885/23551)   \15Compressing objects:   9% (2120/23551)   \15Compressin

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2g objects:  10% (2356/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  11% (2591/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  12% (2827/23551)   \15Compressing 

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2objects:  13% (3062/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  14% (3298/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  15% (3533/23551)   \15Compressing ob

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2jects:  16% (3769/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  17% (4004/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  18% (4240/23551)   \15Compressing obje

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2cts:  19% (4475/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  20% (4711/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  21% (4946/23551)   \15Compressing object

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2s:  22% (5182/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  23% (5417/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  24% (5653/23551)   \15Compressing objects:

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2  25% (5888/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  26% (6124/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  27% (6359/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  28% (6595/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  29% (6830/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  30% (7066/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  31% (7301/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  32% (7537/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  33% (7772/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  34% (8008/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  35% (8243/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  36% (8479/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  37% (8714/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  38% (8950/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  39% (9185/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  40% (9421/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  41% (9656/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  42% (9892/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  43% (10127/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  44% (10363/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  45% (10598/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  46% (10834/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  47% (11069/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  48% (11305/23551)   

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2\15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  49% (11540/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  50% (11776/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  51% (12012/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  52% (12247/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  53% (12483/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  54% (12718/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  55% (12954/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  56% (13189/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  57% (13425/23551)   

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2\15Compressing objects:  58% (13660/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  59% (13896/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  60% (14131/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  61% (14367/23551)   

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2\15Compressing objects:  62% (14602/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  63% (14838/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  64% (15073/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  65% (15309/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  66% (15544/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  67% (15780/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  68% (16015/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  69% (16251/23551)   \15

remote: Counting objects: 86496, done.        

remote: Compressing objects:   0% (1/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:   1% (236/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:   2% (472/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:   3% (707/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:   4% (943/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:   5% (1178/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:   6% (1414/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:   7% (1649/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:   8% (1885/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:   9% (2120/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  10% (2356/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  11% (2591/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  12% (2827/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  13% (3062/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  14% (3298/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  15% (3533/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  16% (3769/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  17% (4004/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  18% (4240/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  19% (4475/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  20% (4711/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  21% (4946/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  22% (5182/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  23% (5417/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  24% (5653/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  25% (5888/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  26% (6124/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  27% (6359/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  28% (6595/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  29% (6830/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  30% (7066/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  31% (7301/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  32% (7537/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  33% (7772/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  34% (8008/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  35% (8243/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  36% (8479/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  37% (8714/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  38% (8950/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  39% (9185/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  40% (9421/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  41% (9656/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  42% (9892/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  43% (10127/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  44% (10363/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  45% (10598/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  46% (10834/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  47% (11069/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  48% (11305/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  49% (11540/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  50% (11776/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  51% (12012/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  52% (12247/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  53% (12483/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  54% (12718/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  55% (12954/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  56% (13189/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  57% (13425/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  58% (13660/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  59% (13896/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  60% (14131/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  61% (14367/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  62% (14602/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  63% (14838/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  64% (15073/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  65% (15309/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  66% (15544/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  67% (15780/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  68% (16015/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  70% (16486/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  71% (16722/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  72% (16957/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  73% (17193/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  74% (17428/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  75% (17664/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  76% (17899/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  77% (18135/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  78% (18370/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  79% (18606/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  80% (18841/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  81% (19077/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  82% (19312/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  83% (19548/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  84% (19783/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  85% (20019/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  86% (20254/23551)   

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2\15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  87% (20490/23551)   \15Compressing objects:  88% (20725/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  89% (20961/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  90% (21196/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  91% (21432/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  92% (21667/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  93% (21903/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  94% (22138/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  95% (22374/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  96% (22609/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  97% (22845/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  98% (23080/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects:  99% (23316/23551)   \15

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \2Compressing objects: 100% (23551/23551)   \15Compressing objects: 100% (23551/23551), done.

23:48:34.904575 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< PACK ...

23:48:34.910576 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 210648 on AKI-TS01' '--pack_header=2,86496'

  69% (16251/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  70% (16486/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  71% (16722/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  72% (16957/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  73% (17193/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  74% (17428/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  75% (17664/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  76% (17899/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  77% (18135/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  78% (18370/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  79% (18606/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  80% (18841/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  81% (19077/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  82% (19312/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  83% (19548/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  84% (19783/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  85% (20019/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  86% (20254/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  87% (20490/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  88% (20725/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  89% (20961/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  90% (21196/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  91% (21432/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  92% (21667/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  93% (21903/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  94% (22138/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  95% (22374/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  96% (22609/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  97% (22845/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  98% (23080/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects:  99% (23316/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23551/23551)           
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23551/23551), done.        

23:48:34.934588 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 210648 on AKI-TS01' '--pack_header=2,86496'

Receiving objects:   0% (1/86496)   
Receiving objects:   1% (865/86496)   
Receiving objects:   2% (1730/86496)   
Receiving objects:   3% (2595/86496)   
Receiving objects:   4% (3460/86496)   
Receiving objects:   5% (4325/86496)   
Receiving objects:   6% (5190/86496)   
Receiving objects:   7% (6055/86496)   
Receiving objects:   8% (6920/86496)   
Receiving objects:   9% (7785/86496)   
Receiving objects:  10% (8650/86496)   
Receiving objects:  11% (9515/86496)   
Receiving objects:  12% (10380/86496)   
Receiving objects:  13% (11245/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  14% (12110/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  15% (12975/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  16% (13840/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  17% (14705/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  18% (15570/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  19% (16435/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  20% (17300/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  21% (18165/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  22% (19030/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  23% (19895/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  24% (20760/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  25% (21624/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  26% (22489/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  27% (23354/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  28% (24219/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  29% (25084/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  30% (25949/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  31% (26814/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  32% (27679/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  33% (28544/86496), 2.39 MiB | 4.73 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  34% (29409/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  34% (29513/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  35% (30274/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  36% (31139/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  37% (32004/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  38% (32869/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  39% (33734/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  40% (34599/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  41% (35464/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  42% (36329/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  43% (37194/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  44% (38059/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  45% (38924/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  46% (39789/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  47% (40654/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  48% (41519/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  49% (42384/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  50% (43248/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  51% (44113/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  52% (44978/86496), 7.80 MiB | 7.75 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  53% (45843/86496), 14.31 MiB | 9.50 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  54% (46708/86496), 14.31 MiB | 9.50 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  54% (47353/86496), 29.12 MiB | 11.62 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  54% (47354/86496), 36.19 MiB | 12.02 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  55% (47573/86496), 44.54 MiB | 12.68 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  56% (48438/86496), 44.54 MiB | 12.68 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  57% (49303/86496), 44.54 MiB | 12.68 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  58% (50168/86496), 48.91 MiB | 12.19 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  58% (50687/86496), 48.91 MiB | 12.19 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  59% (51033/86496), 48.91 MiB | 12.19 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  60% (51898/86496), 48.91 MiB | 12.19 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  61% (52763/86496), 48.91 MiB | 12.19 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  62% (53628/86496), 48.91 MiB | 12.19 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  63% (54493/86496), 48.91 MiB | 12.19 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  64% (55358/86496), 55.95 MiB | 12.40 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  65% (56223/86496), 55.95 MiB | 12.40 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  66% (57088/86496), 55.95 MiB | 12.40 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  66% (57585/86496), 62.34 MiB | 13.30 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  66% (57585/86496), 64.13 MiB | 955.00 KiB/s   
Connection reset by 195.<REDACTED>

fatal: early EOF
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: index-pack failed
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2430)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2044)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:81)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:569)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:798)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1122)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1167)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
```

Due to this being a public post, I had to remove some information from the log entries by replacing it with 'REDACTED'.

Some more information regarding the environment, we are using Bitbucket server, which is installed in our internal network. Not sure if this is relevant, but thought I'd mention it.

Another thing to mention is that I've had the exact same error happen also when doing a checkout in the command line, so it's not necessarily related to Jenkins. The more I look into it, it seems to be a problem in git itself, but I really don't know.

I've been struggling with this issue for about a year now and it's becoming unmaintainable as we are starting to expand our automated environments!
Please let me know if you have encountered this and/or if you have any idea on how to solve it!
Thank you!

Comment: "Connection reset by <host>" means that your machine sent something to their machine, and their machine said "go away, I'm not talking to you". You need to figure out why that happened: it could be a router issue, or it could be a problem on either end or on both ends. Use some kind of packet tracer (tcpdump, wireshark, etc) at both ends and capture the packets from around the failure time.

Comment: The huge drop in throughput (from MiB/s to KiB/s) is an indication that their end stopped sending to your end, but why *that* happened remains unknown. It suggests that eventually, your end said "hello? you still on the line?" and they said no.